# filter query param not working through axios get from my vue js application?

Tags: vue.js, axios, query-string

whenever a user types anything into the textfield, an  axios get request to the url
[http://sandbox4.wootz.io:8080/api/data/1/action/?filter={id}like'%TE%'](http://sandbox4.wootz.io:8080/api/data/1/action/?filter=%7Bid%7Dlike%27%TE%%27)   is made and it is supposed to return back all the filtered results based on the search(what user has typed) as a response. But currently rather than returning the filtered results as a response it is giving out all results(non-filtered results).

NOTE: I have tested the above mentioned URL through postman by making a get request and it gave out the filtered results perfectly.Why is the same not happening through my application code?plz help

```js
 getAsyncDataAction: debounce(function(name) {
      if (!name.length) {
        this.dataAction = [];
        return;
      }
      this.isFetching = true;
    
      api
        .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/action/?filter={id}like'%${name}%'`)    
        .then(response => {
          this.dataAction = [];
                  response.forEach(item => {
            this.dataAction.push(item);
          });
          console.log('action results are'+JSON.stringify(this.dataAction)) //displays all the results(non-filtered)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.dataAction = [];
          throw error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isFetching = false;
        });
    }, 500),
```

api.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const props = {
  base_url: '/api/store',
  search_url: '/api/entity/search',
  cors_url: 'http://localhost',
  oper_url: '/api'
};

axios.defaults.headers.get['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = props.cors_url;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = props.cors_url;
axios.defaults.headers.patch['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = props.cors_url;

async function getSearchData(key, path) {
  try {
    console.log('inside getSearchData path value is'+path)
    console.log('inside getSearchData and url for axios get is '+props.base_url + '/data' + path)

    let response = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: props.base_url + '/data' + path,
      headers: {'session_id': key}
    });

    if (response.status == 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not encoding the query string correctly. In particular, your `%` signs need to become `%25`

To do this, I highly recommend using the `params` options in Axios.

For example

```js
async function getSearchData(key, path, params) { //  added "params"

  // snip

  let response = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${props.base_url}/data${path}`,
    params, //  use "params" here
    headers: {'session_id': key}
  });
```

and call your function with

```js
const params = {}

// check for empty or blank "name"
if (name.trim().length > 0) {
  params.filter = `{id}like'%${name}%'`
}

api
  .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key, '/action/', params)
```

---

Alternatively, encode the query parameter manually

```js
const filter = encodeURIComponent(`{id}like'%${name}%'`)
const path = `/action/?filter=${filter}`
```

Which should produce something like

```
/action/?filter=%7Bid%7Dlike'%25TE%25'
```

Comment: hi i tried the params option and it is filtering the results . But i want to ignore case ie, should include for both uppercase and lowercase charecter

Comment: should be case insensitive

Comment: UPDATE: sorry correction it should show all the possible results (the total results) upon clicking into the input field ie,on focus

Comment: Filtering and ignoring case is something your back-end should be doing. There's nothing you can do on the front-end to achieve that